# How to load page only after JavaScript function has finished executing and performed its magic?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Here's the story...**

I have an image that is of dimensions 1174px x 660px within a container of dimensions 1174px x 375px. The image's height is cutoff and only 375 pixels worth of the image's height is displayed as I set overflow hidden on the container.

I have created a JavaScript function that takes this image (1174x660) and vertically centers it in its container (1174x 375) so that the center of the image is at the center of the container.

```
function allFeaturesImagesResize () {
    var allFeatures = function () {
        var image = $('.all-features article img'),
            container = $('.all-features article'),
            container_height = container.height(),
            image_height = image.height(),
            container_center = .5 * container_height,
            image_center = .5 * image_height,
            center = (image_center - container_center);
            image.css('position','relative').css('bottom', center);

    }
    $(function () {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            allFeatures();
        }).resize();
    });
}
```

I am using a `$(document).ready(function() { //... });` wrapper around this function, however, whenever the page loads I can see the function doing its work of moving the image up to the center point. Is there any way to delay the pay load until after this repositioning is complete?

**Keep in mind my site is fluid responsive which is why I need to dynamically position the images as I don't know the user's viewport beforehand dimensions (specifically the width).**

Comment: Why are you using javascript to center the image? IMO, you should just use an empty "div" with the image as the background, then use CSS to center the background.. This will ensure you're image is centered before it is displayed. (I believe)

Comment: The images are being populated via WordPress CMS....

Comment: and if you still insist on using script, set `visibility:hidden` on the image initially and then remove the style.

Comment: Oh I see. That is interesting.  Pretty sure you can't manipulate objects in the DOM, until they're actually in the DOM.  So the image would have to be rendered (albeit in the wrong spot), then the JS is parsed and it moves the image.  I don't have much experience with wordpress, so I wish I could help more.  Can you style the div that the "inserted" image is put into so that it centers it vertically/horizontally?

Comment: @Drewdiddy611 - unfortunately no...

Comment: I personally do not see why the fact that the images are being populated by a CMS would stop you from using them as a background and centering them using CSS. your script just as well could set the style of the container appropriately.

Comment: @akonsu One thing I didn't mention in the original question (just updated it now with this info): Keep in mind my site is fluid responsive which is why I need to dynamically position the images as I don't know the user's viewport beforehand.

Comment: I think to achieve what Matt wants, using script is out of the question, since the item you want to manipulate is, in fact, an item in the DOM, so it's only accessible after it's been "loaded" on the page. Using script, you can access elements during page load (although after element load, and not recommended), but since Matt wants this to happen before page load, it would only be viable in CSS.

Comment: @Drewdiddy611 Perhaps I could use a loading graphic until all the resizing has taken place? In effect, use a callback function to the original function I posted and once that's finished resizing remove the loading graphic and display the images?

Comment: @Matt Or hide it as `akonsu` mentioned earlier. :) Which was an option I initially thought about mentioning, but I didn't know if it would be viable for you or not.. Yes indeed, a loading graphic is the simplest, and probably the easiest option, if you can't manipulate the CSS environment.

Comment: try making the container invisible until the script has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `load` instead of `ready` event. `$(window).load(function(){ ... your code }` will tell that the code should be executed only after all images are loaded. `ready` event will be fired when the DOM is loaded even if the images are not finished loading

Note that you are selecting multiple images `$('.all-features article img')`. By doing `images.height()` it will only get the height of the first found image. The same for the line that select multiple container.

Your code should be translate into "For each image found do" : `$('.all-features article img').each (function(){...});`

Comment: They still need to be in the DOM to be centered no?

Comment: Yes. And to determine the width/height of the image, the image has to be 100% loaded. window.load will make sure your code will not executed sooner than that.

Comment: @ThanhTrung - Giving this a try now... :)

Comment: Would such a thing be possible? jQuery(window).load(function ($) { //... });

Comment: Yes and no. The $ is useless

Comment: Doesn't that make $ usable within the closure without conflicting with other libraries that potentially use $?

Comment: Above you used `$(document).ready`, change it into `$(window).ready`. Nothing magic here. There is a noConflict function for conflict problem. $ stands for window.jQuery

Comment: Ok...but aren't you suggesting for me to use this: $(window).load(function(){ ... your code }

Comment: Yes, just try it first, then discuss later... Sry. It's $(window).load